# JQuery vs GWT

Tags: jquery, gwt

Разрабатываю веб UI. Встал вопрос о выборе библиотеки контролов для него. После некоторых исследований данной области, встал вопрос о выборе между JQuery и GWT. UI планируется отображать на планшетных ПК, нет-буках, и мобильных устройствах (таких как iPhone и android). У GWT есть версии под мобильные платформы, JQuery тоже имеет большой набор библиотек под разные платформы. Кто сталкивался с подобным вопросом? В чью пользу был сделан выбор и почему?

Answer (score 3):

Лично я сделал выбор с пользу *GWT* из-за уважения к Google и, конечно, потому, что на *Java* писать код мне привычнее чем на *JavaScript+JQuery*.

*GWT* имеет более совершенную объектную систему и вы даже не почувствуете, что программируете для веб, а не для десктопа. Возможно, такой выбор я сделал из-за большого опыта работы со *Swing*, после которого *GWT* мне показался интуитивно понятным. К тому же мощный механизм GWT-RPC (асинхронные вызовы процедур) лишают необходимости в сериализации. В общем, в *GWT* я вижу сплошные плюсы. Но нельзя говорить, что *GWT* однозначно на порядок лучше. *GWT* очень удобен для *RIA*, а для разной анимации и меню на странице лучше подойдет *JQuery*.